# Preview camera is rotated 90º when device is on Landscape

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing an app based on a sample of this repo (https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/ios/ImageClassification/Camera%20Feed/CameraFeedManager.swift). I have built the same structure for getting preview camera as the sample, so I start App on portrait mode and preview camera work correctly. But, I change to landscapeRigh or I set to app as only mode the landscaperight and.... preview is rotated 90º.
I have tried to use the command:
`videoDataOutput.connection(with: .video)?.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight`
But it doesn't work… I can set all modes and it always has the same behaviour.
Could you give me some advice to fix this problem? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the preview layer's connection `.videoOrientation`

I grabbed that example, created a new project, and stripped it down to the basics -- no TensorFlow references, no clipboard images, no buttons / options, etc.

This will create a `280 x 280` video view at `40,40` (upper-left). The ***only*** thing you need from the repo you linked to is `CameraFeedManager.swift`:

No `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` connections... just create a new view controller and assign its custom class to `MyTestViewController`:

import AVFoundation
import UIKit

```
class MyTestViewController: UIViewController {

    var previewView: PreviewView = {
        let v = PreviewView()
        return v
    }()

    private lazy var cameraCapture = CameraFeedManager(previewView: previewView)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        previewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(previewView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            previewView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            previewView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            previewView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 280.0),
            previewView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previewView.widthAnchor),
        ])

        cameraCapture.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        #if !targetEnvironment(simulator)
        cameraCapture.checkCameraConfigurationAndStartSession()
        #endif
    }

    #if !targetEnvironment(simulator)
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        cameraCapture.stopSession()
    }
    #endif

    private func updatePreviewLayer(layer: AVCaptureConnection, orientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation) {
        layer.videoOrientation = orientation
        previewView.previewLayer.frame = previewView.frame
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        if let connection =  self.previewView.previewLayer.connection  {
            let currentDevice: UIDevice = UIDevice.current
            let orientation: UIDeviceOrientation = currentDevice.orientation
            let previewLayerConnection: AVCaptureConnection = connection

            if previewLayerConnection.isVideoOrientationSupported {

                switch (orientation) {
                case .portrait:
                    updatePreviewLayer(layer: previewLayerConnection, orientation: .portrait)
                    break

                case .landscapeRight:
                    updatePreviewLayer(layer: previewLayerConnection, orientation: .landscapeLeft)
                    break

                case .landscapeLeft:
                    updatePreviewLayer(layer: previewLayerConnection, orientation: .landscapeRight)
                    break

                case .portraitUpsideDown:
                    updatePreviewLayer(layer: previewLayerConnection, orientation: .portraitUpsideDown)
                    break

                default:
                    updatePreviewLayer(layer: previewLayerConnection, orientation: .portrait)
                    break
                }

            }
        }
    }

}

// MARK: CameraFeedManagerDelegate Methods
extension MyTestViewController: CameraFeedManagerDelegate {

    func didOutput(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
        // do something with the output
    }

    // MARK: Session Handling Alerts
    func sessionWasInterrupted(canResumeManually resumeManually: Bool) {
        print("session was interrupted")
    }

    func sessionInterruptionEnded() {
        print("session interruption ended")
    }

    func sessionRunTimeErrorOccured() {
        print("session runtime error")
    }

    func presentCameraPermissionsDeniedAlert() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Camera Permissions Denied", message: "Camera permissions have been denied for this app. You can change this by going to Settings", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default) { (action) in
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        alertController.addAction(settingsAction)

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func presentVideoConfigurationErrorAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Camera Configuration Failed", message: "There was an error while configuring camera.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}

// MARK: PreviewView
class PreviewView: UIView {

    var shouldUseClipboardImage: Bool = false

    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
        guard let layer = layer as? AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer else {
            fatalError("Layer expected is of type VideoPreviewLayer")
        }
        return layer
    }

    var session: AVCaptureSession? {
        get {
            return previewLayer.session
        }
        set {
            previewLayer.session = newValue
        }
    }

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
    }

}
```

Comment: Very thanks!!! With your sample I have understood what happen, I set the orientation before that it was renderer so it didn't work me.